# combineReducers for better redux store naming

Tags: reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6, react-redux

Does it make sense to `combineReducers` simply to rename a key-value pair in the redux store? Something like this

```
const userReducer = combineReducers({
  login: loginReducer,
  session: sessionReducer,
});
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  user: userReducer,
});
```

Accessing `state.user` using `useSelector` feels more intuitive.

Currenty, I have a login and session reducer for grabbing user information from a backend API and populating the store.

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  login: loginReducer,
  session: sessionReducer,
});
```

However, I found myself accessing the user object returned by this react-redux hook

```
const { user } = useSelector((state: RootState) => ({
  user: state.session,
  // or user: state.login,
}));
```

my login and session reducers both return the same user data but different API calls are made to get this user data. If the `user` data looks the same, I was wondering if I could just combine the session and login reducers for a `userReducer`

Comment: Interesting question, since hooks I personnally stopped to put the state in the store, I put the reducer in the container if state is not shared with other containers. If shared with others, I use useContext. 
I would be really interested by why you do not use useContext only

Comment: @NielsDominguez I am learning hooks right now so I don't have any "context" on `useContext` =P

Comment: Why do you have two reducers loginReducer and sessionReducer if both of them have the same data. Also you could have simply returned `const session = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.session);` The is no need to return an object and then destructuring it

Comment: Ok, I recommend you to have a look at useContext, it is basically same as redux, but without thinking too much.

Comment: Context is _not at all_ "basically the same as Redux". Context is simply a mechanism to make a single value accessible to a nested React component subtree.  It's up to you to decide what that value is and how it should be managed, which is typically done via React component state APIs.  Totally not the same as Redux.

Comment: @markerikson Hello mark, with context you can pass any reducer/action same as redux store. Also we can combine useMemo with React context, it is not the equivalent of selectors?  Also we can build a similar architecture. So why using redux please if performance and architecture are similar?
Thank you for all your work and your expertise on this.

Comment: No, they aren't at all equivalent. Please read my posts [React, Redux and Context Behavior](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/01/blogged-answers-react-redux-and-context-behavior/), [The History and Implementation of React Redux](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/11/react-redux-history-implementation/), and [A (Mostly) Complete Guide to React Rendering Behavior](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/) for technical details on how the performance differs.

Comment: As for "why use Redux", see my post [Redux - Not Dead Yet!](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/03/redux-not-dead-yet/), which compares the use cases for Redux vs several other options.  Again, (React-)Redux and Context are _different_ tools, that solve _different_ problems.